# Haskell Non-Exhaustion

Tags: haskell, recursion, non-exhaustive-patterns

I was wondering if anyone could help me identify the part of the haskell code that would be non-exhaustive? I can't see how the base case isn't met at the end of the list.

thanks a lot

Jonny

```
type Rule
  = (Char, String)

type Rules
  = [Rule]

type System
  = (Float, String, Rules)

cross, triangle, arrowHead, peanoGosper,
  dragon, snowflake, tree, bush :: System

type Vertex
  = (Float, Float)

type TurtleState
  = (Vertex, Float)

type Stack
  = [TurtleState]

type ColouredLine
  = (Vertex, Vertex, Colour)


trace :: String -> Float -> Colour -> [ColouredLine]

trace rules angle colour = traceState rules ((0,0),90) []

  where

    traceState :: String -> TurtleState -> Stack -> [ColouredLine]
    traceState [] _ _ = []
    traceState (x:xs) t (y:ys)
      |x == '[' = traceState xs t (t : (y:ys))
      |x == ']' = traceState xs t ys
      |x == 'F' = biggieSmalls : traceState xs t (nextY:ys)
      |otherwise = traceState xs angledY (angledY:ys)
        where
          biggieSmalls = (fst(t),fst(nextY),colour)
          nextY = move 'F' t angle
          angledY = move x t angle
```

Comment: You haven't matched `traceState [_] _ []`. If you compile with warnings on, GHC should give an example of an unmatched pattern.

Comment: Pass `-Wall` to ghc or ghci to enable warnings.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help guys! How can I fix this? I've turned on warnings now (thanks Chi!) and tried to fix the un-matched patterns (thanks Benjamin!). I'm still struggling with what to put there to make it correct!

Answer (score 1):

As Benjamin Hodgson noted, you haven't matched the case where the `rules` string is non-empty (`(_ : _)` as opposed to `[]`) but the `Stack` is empty. That case will arise immediately because the initial stack `trace` passes to `traceState` is in fact `[]`.

To fix the warning/exception, you'll need to either rewrite the second equation for `traceState` as `traceState (x : xs) t y` or to write a third equation, `tracestate (x : xs) t []`. With the former solution, you can then use `case y of` to pattern-match on `y`. Either way, you need to determine how to handle the situation where the list is empty.

The problem will actually arise with a call like `traceState "]" t []`, i.e. if the first parameter to `trace` begins with a "]" or "F". It looks like that'd be an invalid input. If that's the case, you probably want to rewrite `trace` and `traceState` to return a `Maybe [ColouredLine]`, or use `Either` to give an error message.